# Translate c++ functions in TypeScript

Tags: c++, typescript, operators, bit

Given the following functions **written in** C++:

```
#define getbit(s,i) ((s)[(i)/8] & 0x01<<(i)%8)
#define setbit(s,i) ((s)[(i)/8] |= 0x01<<(i)%8)
```

How can I turn them into compatible TypeScript functions?

I came up with:

```
function setbit(s: string, i: number): number {
    return +s[i / 8] | 0x01 << i % 8;
}

function getbit(s: string, i: number): number {
   return +s[i / 8] & 0x01 << i % 8;
}
```

I found out that the `a |= b` equivalent is `a = a | b`, but I'm not sure about the getbit function implementation. Also, I don't really understand what those functions are supposed to do. Could someone explain them, please?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Using the ideas from @Thomas, I ended up doing this:

```
function setBit(x: number, mask: number) {
    return x | 1 << mask;
}

// not really get, more like a test
function getBit(x: number, mask: number) {
    return ((x >> mask) % 2 !== 0);
}
```

since I don't really need a string for the binary representation.

Comment: Those are not C++ functions . Those are macros - They do not have types

Comment: Well... they are written in C++. Not present in C++ library, yes. I've used the wrong words.

Comment: @EdHeal I don' understand why do you downvote a question only because you don't like the way it was asked... you can clarify this even without downvoting. Some people don't have many reputation to afford losing it on random things...

Comment: In JavaScript, variables/function arguments/function return values are not declared as being any particular type, so the JS you show isn't valid (regardless of whether the calculations are correct or not). Why would you try to translate functions (macros) that you don't understand in the first place?

Comment: @EdHeal sorry then, I just assumed that since you were the only one who commented on it.

Comment: @nnnnnn could you be more specific why this isn't valid ES6 code? To my understanding, the C++ code should set the <i> bit from the memory of s or check if it was set or not. ES6 doesn't work with memory but I thought I could emulate the process somehow.

Comment: I was specific. You can't declare variables/arguments as being a type. So `function setbit(s: string, i: number): number { }` should be `function setbit(s, i) { }`. If `s` is an integer then you could do bitwise operations on it. (If it is a string as implied by the `s:string` in your invalid code then it doesn't make sense to check bits.)

Comment: @nnnnnn ah, I'm sorry. I was confusing ES6 with TypeScript... this is TypeScript code. >.>

Comment: @AlexFlorin If you want to port some code to another language, you should first understand how exactly it works. Because as mentioned in my answer, unlike in C++, in JS or Typescript a string is not a good storage method for bits/flags; not if you're going to change them all the time. And if you change this for these two utilities you'll have to make bigger modifications to rest of the lib. So you should understand the optimizations done for one language and know wich optimizations are needed for the other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings ain't a good storage here. And btw, JS Strings use 16bit characters, so you're using only 1/256th of the storage possible.

```
function setbit(string, index) {
    //you could do `index >> 3` but this will/may fail if index > 0xFFFFFFFF
    //well, fail as in produce wrong results, not as in throwing an error.
    var position = Math.floor(index/8), 
        bit = 1 << (index&7),
        char = string.charCodeAt(position);
    return string.substr(0, position) + String.fromCharCode(char|bit) + string.substr(position+1);
}

function getbit(string, index) {
    var position = Math.floor(i/8),
        bit = 1 << (i&7),
        char = string.charCodeAt(position);
    return Boolean(char & bit);
}
```

better would be a (typed) Array.

```
function setBit(array, index){
    var position = Math.floor(index/8),
        bit = 1 << (index&7);
    array[position] |= bit; //JS knows `|=` too
    return array;
}

function getBit(array, index) {
    var position = Math.floor(index/8),
        bit = 1 << (index&7);
    return Boolean(array[position] & bit)
}

var storage = new Uint8Array(100);
setBit(storage, 42);
console.log(storage[5]);

var data = [];
setBit(data, 42);
console.log(data);
```

works with both, but:

- all typed Arrays have a fixed length that can not be changed after memory allocation (creation).
- regular arrays don't have a regular type, like 8bit/index or so, limit is 53Bit with floats, but for performance reasons you should stick with up to INT31 (31, not 32), that means 30bits + sign. In this case the JS engine can optimize this thing a bit behind the scenes; reduce memory impact and is a little faster.

But if performance is the topic, use Typed Arrays! Although you have to know in advance how big this thing can get.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand how to use it.

In the setbit from C++, given something like this:
`unsigned char finalPos = 0x00;`
after applying `setbit(finalPos, 3);`, the result is `8 '\b'` in finalPos.

I think I mislead when I wrote `s: string` in the question, because it was an `unsigned char` in C++.

Comment: @AlexFlorin Sry, been a while since I dealt with C(++) but imo It should be some kind of char[] or char*, otherwise `(s)[(i)/8]` this part would make no sense. Anyway, since Strings in JS are primitives, they cannot be mutated and therefore you have to return the new string. Besides that, `setBit(value:int, bit:uint):int{ return value | 1<<(bit&31) }` so that `setBit(0x00, 3)`also results in `8`. To get `'\\b'` you'll have to run this through `String.fromCharCode()`. And we're back to understanding the structures in both languages and porting the logic, not the code.